# Why are digital tracks louder than digitized vinyls?

Tags: recording

I am currently digitizing some of my vinyls for a DJ gig. Those tracks end up being less loud than tracks which I bought digitally. Is that to be expected due to the different mastering of music for vinyl production?

I have a REGA fono mini A2D phono amplifier which goes via usb directly into Ableton. There I record the audio and then render it at 44.100 Hz to both wave (32bit) and mp3 (320CBR) files during which I normalize.

Comment: Do you normalize?

Comment: Yeah, I do that, thought I'd mentioned it. Thx for asking.

Comment: All new [past 15 years or so] tracks, or are you seeing this mainly on older tracks? You probably need to read up on the "loudness war". There is a chance that even newer vinyl hasn't gone through this massive over-compression.

Comment: Yes, there _might_ be different mastering for vinyl, as there are physical limitations of the medium, especially with heavily compressed or clipped material, see https://www.soundonsound.com/sound-advice/q-how-does-mastering-differ-vinyl-and-digital-releases But there can be a different reason, e.g. some phase shift during digitization produces larger peaks (which decreases average loudness to peak ratio), or something else....

Comment: I wouldn't even rule out that vinyls are mastered differently because vinyl buyers expect different sound (which is kind of backwards because digital audio has more dynamic range)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is absolutely different mastering for vinyl. Whether the original mix has a separate vinyl master or whether a digital master was further processed for vinyl, you can’t cut right into vinyl from a stereo mix or master. You have to do lat/vert limiting and RIAA equalization at a bare minimum.

Modern mixes are very likely to have separate vinyl masters that have a larger crest factor because a small crest factor can be harder to cut into vinyl and vinyl consumers expect larger crest factors.

Vinyl masters made before the late 1990s will have larger crest factors than any digital masters made after that time because there wasn’t the technology available before then to reduce the crest factor to the degree that some masters have it reduced to (as mentioned in a comment, this is part of the loudness wars).

Crest factor is the difference between average and peak level. A larger crest factor usually sounds better than a smaller one, but it also can sound “quieter”, because the maximum peak level for digital audio is fixed, so digital audio with a larger crest factor has to have a lower average level, because the peak cannot be raised.

The maximum peak level for vinyl is different. If the running time of the audio is shorter, then you can have a larger maximum lateral (“lat”) excursion. That means a shorter record could have higher decorrelated (between left and right) peaks. Correlated peaks (cut with vertical or “vert” excursions) are limited by the thickness of the vinyl itself, which means some records can be louder by pressing them into thicker vinyl blanks.

Either way, vinyl doesn’t work as well with the very low crest factors that have been used far too often in digital formats. And vinyl consumers want larger crest factors.

So when you match the peak level of a digital master to the peak level of a vinyl master, you can often find the average level of the vinyl master is lower, which makes it sound quieter. This is a benefit of vinyl, not a weakness.

Comment: Do you know what are the actual typical practices? Is separate mastering done for vinyl, or perhaps just some final stage of mastering done separately for digital and vinyl, or rather digital master is processed further for vinyl?

Comment: I agree that it's different mastering for vinyl, but I have to point out a couple of details. First, the lateral excursion encodes same-phase waveform so that it's compatible with mono players. Vertical excursion encodes opposite phase, and because it's limited vinyl players have limited channel separation. Cartridges have two coils at 45 degree angles, so the channel separation doesn't need any electronics.

Comment: Second, the lateral excursion is limited by tracking ability of the cartridge and physical space on the record. I'm not sure why these would be different for shorter bursts. The has to be enough room between the grooves for maximum excursion anyway, because the beats may be aligned. Some records that have beat that is exact multiple of 33 1/3 or 45 bpm even have visible radial pattern where the bass drum is aligned.

Comment: @user1079505 it differs according to the budget, essentially. On the lowest end of the scale (self funded bands etc) you may just send the master (hopefully minus a bit of master dynamics etc) to a cheap pressing house that will put on the bare minimum extra processing to get it physically onto the record and be done. OTOH a big mastering house will take your mix file and deliver it to the respective rooms for mastering vinyl and mastering CD and the files never meet again from that point. Places like this will offer consultation and test pressings throughout the process.

Comment: edit, in my comment above the first mention of 'master' should read 'mix' or 'mix master'.

Comment: Also: If you were to record and digitize the playback of a digital track, and then normalize that recording, it will be quieter than the original track.  The original track is going to be clipped or limited very close to (or exactly at) 0dBFS.  Your recording will not be a perfect clone, so it will have some peaks sticking out further than others, and it's the highest peaks that control the normalized level.

Comment: Another limitation is that there is a very real limit on the level that can be cut at high frequency. There are both geometric limits (on both cutting and playback) and a rather nasty +6dB/octave slope on the power required to be dissipated in the cutting head. Try to cut something sibilant too hot and first the HF limiters will limit severely, and then if you keep it up the cutter thermal trip will activate (If you are lucky, before the drive coils in ~$10k worth of head burn out). Because of this brick wall limiting is just not useful in a vinyl cutting chain.

Comment: @DanMills: I would think that thermal issues when cutting vinyl could be dealt with by cutting a record at half speed or quarter speed, so I'm a bit surprised they'd be a problem in any scenarios where the geometric issues wouldn't render a record unplayable.

Comment: @supercat Interesting idea. I doubt it’s done in practice because at half speed all the frequencies are halved (of course) and that could be a problem because you’d have to make a custom RIAA curve and time constants for limiters would be off and you might not be able to get the low end right at all. You can’t just arbitrarily make a half-frequency analog signal chain. Also how would you hear if it’s going to sound right?

Comment: @ToddWilcox: One would presumably have to digitally process the audio driving the cutter in order to compensate the frequency response, and developing accurate digital models would probably require carving a bunch of test records, but digitally processing the signal before cutting could probably significantly reduce distortion that would otherwise result from the fact that the contact point of a record player needle will shift in response to the waveform it is following.

Comment: @supercat Half speed cutting is a thing, historically mainly for the various quadraphonic formats and the like that had ultrasonic carriers that needed to be cut. Assuming a flat source all you need to do is double the values of the IRIAA time constant capacitors and reduce the amplitude by 6dB (The output of the IRIAA circuit is a velocity signal), the limiters REALLY should not be activating at this point. The heat was enough of a problem that injecting a trickle of helium into the drive coil gaps was commonplace (Helium has MUCH better heat transfer then air).

Comment: @supercat Half speed cutting predates digital audio in a music production context, but doing it with a preview Studer as a source took a little minor hackery in that both the NAB (Tape replay curve) and the IRIAA (flat to velocity curve) needed tweaks, which actually typically collapsed to a single combined RC network. All professional cutters are  feedback designs so when combined with the feedback electronics they have an essentially flat velocity response.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The change to the IRIAA board is just to add a relay that doubles all the time constants (Usually easiest to just parallel extra caps) and drop the drive level to the feedback board by 6dB. Even cutting at full speed, the 'listen to feedback' is mainly a diagnostics thing, it never sounds quite the same as the product. Many people find the acoustic sound from the cutter head a more useful indicator of problems, you can apparently tell if a sapphire goes bad during a cut. Half speed is not particularly common but it is a thing.